# Reloading row contains UITextField with a rightView causes infinite loop and memory overflow

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I'm facing a strange bug about reloading a `UITableViewCell` contains `UITextField` with a custom `rightView`.

I created a very simple example to demonstrate the bug:

My custom cell with a `UITextField`:

```
@implementation TableViewCell

- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    if (self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {
        _textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
        _textField.text = @"This is a text field";
        [self.contentView addSubview:_textField];
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

My view controller with a `UITableView`:

```
@interface ViewController () <UITableViewDataSource>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (nonatomic) UIView *rightView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // Press to reload the row with rightView
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(reloadRow)];

    // Create rightView and store to a property
    _rightView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 24, 24)];
    _rightView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    [_tableView registerClass:[TableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    _tableView.dataSource = self;
}

- (void)reloadRow {
    [_tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0
                                                            inSection:0]]
                      withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic)];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textField.rightView = _rightView;
    cell.textField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;

    return cell;
}

@end
```

[image: App screenshot]

That's it. Then I press the reload button. The infinite loop starts, application hangs. After some seconds, the app crashes because it uses too much memory:

`Terminated due to memory error.`

But, if I don't store the `rightView` in a property, and create new view each time `tableView` dequeue the cell, then there will be no problem.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textField.rightView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 24, 24)];
    cell.textField.rightView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    cell.textField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;

    return cell;
}
```

But my `rightView` (in real app) is not a simple view so I don't want to re-create it everytime the row shows up.

Anyone knows why this happened? Why it didn't happen if I don't store the `rightView`? Thanks for reading.

Comment: why you don't create the right view inside your TableViewCell like the textfield?

Comment: I have one subclass of `UITableViewCell` to use in every place in the app, and I only use `rightView` in one view controller so I don't wan't to add it inside the cell subclass.

Comment: The right way is to use different UITableViewCell classes, not only one all over the app :-)

Answer (score 0):

You try add one view to multiple `superview`. you can't do that. Your `@property (nonatomic) UIView *rightView` can have only one `superView`. Try delete it from subviews `cell.textField.subviews`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    for (UIView *subview in cell.textField.subviews) {
        if ([subview isEqual:_rightView]) {
           [subview removeFromSuperView];
        }
    }
    cell.textField.rightView = _rightView;
    cell.textField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;

    return cell;
}
```

Or make a fabric method that will return instance of `rightView`

Comment: I tried what you say but the problem is still there. And yes I made a method to create a new `rightView` every time the cell needs it, that solves the problem but as I said, my custom view is not a simple view so I don't want to recreate it many times because it would make the tableView flickering while scrolling.

Comment: I'm a bit changed my answer, try diff way delete from subviews